# Listing all VPN directories that can be mapped to a drive instead of accessing them one by one

Tags: networking, vpn

Things that are good to know about me before reading my question:

- I'm using Windows.
- I have access to Linux and Ubuntu.
- I don't have very much networking experience.
- In terms of network engineering knowledge, I'm basically a single-celled organism compared to any sysadmin.

So I'm trying to find a certain file on a VPN. I basically want to know the topology of the entire VPN. The default drive that is mapped on initial connection is `dogscats.example.com` but it is possible to type, into Windows Explorer, `\\cats.example.com` to map `cats.example.com` onto another drive.

There are a few locations that are accessible, that probably shouldn't be, by doing this. (Guessing `\\birds.example.com`, for example, will get you into `birds.example.com`). Is there a PowerShell command or otherwise that will list every possible connection that can be mapped to a local drive (`*.example.com` or something)? Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, firstly, all the VPN is doing is putting you on the same network (LAN) as some other computers. Nothing about the VPN itself will tell you what other machines are available on the network. Any network discovery methods would be the same as if your machine were physically on the same LAN.

---

### Share types

Given that you can directly access these machines' shared folders via Windows Explorer, it can be assumed that they are either SMB or FTP shares.

If they are FTP shares, there's really not much you can do to map them. FTP shares work over the internet, and can point to any public IP address.

However, IIRC, the `\\computername` path in Windows is only for SMB shares. Here, you do have a few options, depending on the network setup.

Given that you are apparently using a fully-qualified domain name, you are probably on an Active Directory (AD) domain, which gives you more options.

---

### Listing SMB shares on the local network

There's a few ways to list available SMB shares. However, none of them are guaranteed to be complete. They all depend on your computer being able to reach them (see: firewalls).

- If legacy SMBv1 is still enabled, you can use the Network item in Windows Explorer (traditionally known as "Network Neighborhood") to discover all SMB shares on the local network. There is a modern replacement, but requires the disabled-by-default "Function Discovery Provider Host" and "Function Discovery Resource Publication" services to be enabled (on both the client and server). This will only work on the local subnet, and not over a routed network.
- If you are within an Active Directory domain, you can use [ADExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer) or other LDAP browsing tool, which can list most computers on the domain — unless your AD admin has taken measures to block this (by restricting read access). This will likely not find any shares hosted by Samba on Linux servers.
- There are tools that use a broadcast request to retrieve a list. I'm not sure if this depends on SMBv1. This will only work on the local subnet, and not over a routed network. For example, https://serverfault.com/questions/160396/listing-available-smb-shares-on-a-network-through-the-command-line-in-linux
- The brute-force approach is always available, with a tool like `nmap`. You can check if SMB ports are open on every IP address within your local subnet (or other networks of your choosing). However, you won't necessarily find them all — especially if your network is large enough to have multiple (routed) subnets, and you don't know what they all are are.
- I'm sure other dedicated auditing tools exist for this purpose. However, most of them will not be more complete than a properly configured `nmap` scan — and, again, they are best used when you know your entire network topology.

---

### Listing subdomains

There is generally no way to list valid subdomains of a domain. The only exception is if the domain has an improperly secured zone transfer option available.

Comment: Well said, and +10 to you.